# Advanced StaggeredGridView with different View with different width

Tags: android, android-gridview, staggered-gridview

I have tried several implementation of Android StaggeredGridView which gives facility to add views of different height in GridView.

My question is - Is it possible to implement StaggeredGridView which contains views with different width and different height? if yes, what could be best possible way to do it?

Answer (score -2):

Try https://github.com/utopiadevelopers/StaggeredGridView This implenmentation of StaggeredGridView allows the colspan, so the views can differ not only in height, but also in width

Comment: Make sure you provide the necessary code within your answer, in case this link changes in the future.

Comment: I apologize for the incorrect answer. After the more detailed investigation of the StaggeredView implementations it found out, that nor of them allows colspan. This feature is planned to be realized in the TwoWayView of LucasRocha [link](http://lucasr.org/2014/07/31/the-new-twowayview/). I am also looking for masonry-like layout, but still can find only implementations of pinterest-like one.